# What hit rating do I need as an undead hunter in PvP to be hitcapped?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

As in the title:

What hit rating do I need as an undead hunter in PvP to be hitcapped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need 5% hit to be capped in PvP, so that works out to about 601 hit rating at level 85 (with 120.190 rating giving you 1% hit).

Sources:
[Cataclysm Hunter Hit Cap and Hit Rating at Level 85](http://www.warcrafthuntersunion.com/2010/11/cataclysm-hunter-hit-cap-and-hit-rating-level-85/)
[Beginner Guide to Hunter PvP: Gearing for PvP](http://www.warcrafthuntersunion.com/2011/03/the-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-hunter-pvp-part-1-gearing-for-pvp-and-racials/)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Looks like 600 for PvP.  http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/1827664302#7

---

You need a 961 rating at level 85 in PvE.  It's the same for Undead as for all others except the Draenei.  http://www.warcrafthuntersunion.com/2010/11/cataclysm-hunter-hit-cap-and-hit-rating-level-85/

Comment: That's for a raid boss. PVP hit cap is a bit lower.

Comment: Ah. All the hits I was getting at first didn't distinguish.